# How to extend css emotion styled base components?

Tags: javascript, css, styled-components, emotion

https://codesandbox.io/s/w242n1vonw

I have a project using styled-system and react-emotion.

I have styled headings that inherit from a base css for reusability.

Sometimes I want to be able to overwrite properties using styled system like:

```
<H1 color='green'/>
```

It's working and fine when my base component is:

```
const BaseHeading = ({ theme, ...props }) => css`
  color: ${props.color ? props.color : theme.secondary};
`;
```

But if I want to potentially override ten properties I need to reuse that props conditional. Is this the idiomatic way to write such functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider this the correct way to approach overriding multiple properties.  If you have other properties that are fixed like `margin` for example, you could do something like below to help clarify your "css" file.

```
const marginMap = {
  sm: '4px',
  md: '8px',
  lg: '10px',
  default: '0',
}

const BaseHeading = styled.header`
  margin: ${({ margin = 'default'}) => marginMap[margin]};
`;
```

You can change `'default'` to be your base theme stylings

But to your question, I haven't seen a better way to overwrite properties using styled system/styled components

Answer (score 9):

You can create a new custom styled component that extends a different styled component using the styled function from @emotion/styled. Let's say you had a styled component called BoldText.

```
const BoldText = styled("div")`
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
`;
```

You can override certain properties of BoldText by creating a new styled component that is built off of BoldText similar to the way BoldText is built off of a div.

```
import styled from "@emotion/styled";
import BoldText from "./BoldText"

const BigBoldText = styled(BoldText)`
  font-size: 20px;
`

<BoldText>I'm bold and 16px</BoldText>
<BigBoldText>I'm bold and 20px</BigBoldText>
```